# Cell phones in multiple European countries?

Tags: europe, cellphones, frankfurt

My college-age son is traveling to Europe next month for a month-long trip, and we are trying to figure out the most straightforward way to get him cell phone access during his trip.  Probably a moderate amount of text/voice/data, but not huge quantities would be needed of any of those.  He lives in the USA and currently has a CDMA Android smartphone that he has through Tracfone.  He will be arriving in Germany (Frankfurt), then traveling north up through Denmark, Sweden, Norway, and Iceland, before flying back to the USA.

We are looking for the easiest way for him to have cell access throughout his trip, whether that is through SIM cards in his current phone, or to just have him buy an inexpensive phone once he arrives in Germany.  He will be staying in a combination of hotels and private residences on this trip, so will not have regular or reliable access to WiFi in many of his locations, so ideally would need something more than Google Voice/Hangouts or other WiFi solution.  Also, he will be traveling as part of a group, so may not have the flexibility to easily wander around either the Frankfurt airport, or anywhere else in Frankfurt to find a cell phone store once he arrives.

Thanks in advance for any advice or suggestions!

Comment: My daughter spent the fall in Spain, using an Orange SIM card in her (US) phone. When we visited, she picked up a few one-month SIM cards for about 20 Euros each, with unlimited data (or certainly enough for text and Google Hangouts between us). Usable across Europe - she used hers in multiple countries with no problems. No affiliation with Orange, they just happened to be the one she picked originally...

Comment: A postpaid account with T-Mobile in the US would be a convenient option, as it includes reasonable amounts of overseas roaming in many countries.

Comment: "CDMA" and "GSM" have not been mutually exclusive for some years, and many phones, even inexpensive ones, have radios that support both technology "tracks." What is more important is knowing which radio frequency bands are supported, as that may limit which carriers he can use in certain countries or areas. The actual model number of the phone might thus be useful to provide.